# 301 Moved Permanently on GET request (some sites) C++

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, get, http-status-code-301

I just want to make a GET request to my telegram bot using C++ code but it's getting `301 Moved Permanently` (but if I use web-browser it works fine).
Request to other sites work just fine, almost with no errors (google.com, ip2c.org ...).

Below I provide the code I'm using:

```
const std::string host = "api.telegram.org";
const std::string target = "/bot1781233486:AAENIwkZt0Lbv9zjks6l-4loBcWDzKyMhyU/sendMessage?chat_id=@ZiyodaEnglishPracticeTracker&text=Test+message+from+bot";

boost::asio::io_context ioc;

boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ioc);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(ioc);
boost::asio::connect(socket, resolver.resolve(host, "80"));

http::request<http::string_body> req(http::verb::get, target, 11);

req.set(http::field::host, host);
req.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);

http::write(socket, req);

{
    boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;
    http::response<http::dynamic_body> res;
    http::read(socket, buffer, res);

    std::cout << res << std::endl;
}
socket.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
```

The bot's token is also shown in the code, it's just a temporary bot, so feel free to test it, but change chat id to see the result.

If you got an error try this one:

```
const std::string host = "ip2c.org";
const std::string target = "/192.199.20.22";
```

This one returns a valid result

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: `301 Moved Permanently` is a redirection. You have to extract the Location header and redo the request for that URL.

Comment: The redirect could be because you're trying access a site which wants to enforce HTTPS using only HTTP

Comment: @Jarod42 My questions was: what is the reason of getting this error in my case? Because if I use this link on the browser it works fine, but I couldn't do it using c++ code

Comment: @rpress Could you, please, more detailed information on how doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to redirect it from HTTP to HTTPS, and the problem was solved by changing the port from 80 to 443